# Ajax request data as jsonp, but parse it as json

Tags: json, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I have an issue trying to make a cross-domain ajax request for a json file. I can reach the file using jsonp, but on the client-side there is no jsonp response, and I have no control over changing that.

Is there a way to reach the file without cross-domain issues, through  jsonp request, but then receive the response as json and parse it as json?

Answer (score 0):

No, the response must be a function invocation.  This is the basis of the JSONP convention.  If you want access to some JSON data from your JSONP call, simply have the response invoke a function on your page, passing in the desired JSON data as a parameter.